# How to make an explorer tree out of a list of links

Tags: jquery

I have a list of topic categories that looks something like this mockup: http://www.problemio.com/problems/categories.php

And what I am trying to do is make each item clickable and expandable into the items that would match up.

I googled for such a thing and found only such things for file trees.  Is there a way to pull this off for the kind of list that I have?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean an accordion if it isn't about trees? Or is it? Your mockup lacks some example of items added somewhere (or I didn't get it).

[**http://hanshillen.github.com/jqtest/**](http://hanshillen.github.com/jqtest/) (from The Paciello Group, funded by AOL - not kidding on this one - and AEGIS itself funded by UE)
In both cases, accordion or tree, these scripts are a sure bet: you can click on Accordion or Tree tabs and see if one of the examples matches your need. The 13 scripts are based on jQuery UI and their accessibility were (highly) improved for ARIA, keyboard, etc